# Deploying an app on Iphone device and on App store

Tags: iphone, deployment, device, store

I am using haskintosh (Snow Leopad 10.6) and I am implementing an Iphone application. I want to deploy my app on device and deploy to App Store. I have already have $99 for paying IOS developer program. However, I am not sure after payment, whether I have a certification and a keychain for deploying or not. Please tell me I should spend $99 or not? or I have to pay a Mac OS license and then spend %99?. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: If you won't chalk up the money to buy a real Mac, is getting an iOS developer license really that worth it?

Answer (score 1):

Certificate is essential to run you app on device or to upload it on App Store, and that certificate is obtained when you pay $99 to apple. I am also doing iphone development on hackintosh and i have obtained a certificate from apple to deploy my apps on AppStore and device and it works fine.